# How to iterate through children with jQuery, store values from CSS properties of each child's background image and use these values on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am building slider using jQuery. I want to build it dynamically so that it works on a different number of slides depending on user input.

The simple example of my code output would look like this if the user created 5 slides through admin dashboard in WordPress:

```
<div class="slides">
    <div class="slide">Slide content with background image</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide content with background image</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide content with background image</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide content with background image</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide content with background image</div>
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <a class="thumbnail_slider_control"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail_slider_control"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail_slider_control"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail_slider_control"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail_slider_control"></a>
</div>
```

Background images are applied through trough CSS background-image property.
I wanted to iterate through all the children of `.slides` and save all background image values inside array (that was my first thought).

Afterward, I would like to loop through `.controls` children and apply the same URLs as the background images of children.

My goal here is to create thumbnail slider navigation so that every control has associated background image applied from slide background image to eliminate the need from users for assigning the same URL on 2 places manually.

I searched for the similar problem here but seems there is no such question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly easy to match control to slide by index then use `css()` as both getter and setter

```js
var $slides = $('.slide');

$('.thumbnail_slider_control').each(function(i){
  $(this).css('backgroundImage', $slides.eq(i).css('backgroundImage') )
})
```

```css
.slide, .thumbnail_slider_control{
  display:block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:50px
}
#slide-1{
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/150x50)
}
#slide-2{
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/000000/ffffff)
}

#slide-3{
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/990000/ffffff)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slides" style="float:left; width:50%">
    Slides
    <div id="slide-1" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="slide-2" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="slide-3"  class="slide"></div>
</div>
<div class="controls"  style="float:right; width:50%">
    Controls
    <a class="thumbnail_slider_control"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail_slider_control"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail_slider_control"></a>       
</div>
```